# exposeFunction very slow with large object argument

Tags: puppeteer

Steps to reproduce
Call exposeFunction with large object

Tell us about your environment:

Puppeteer version: puppeteer@13.5.1
Platform / OS version: Windows 11
URLs (if applicable):
Node.js version: v16.15.0
Please include code that reproduces the issue.

pup.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.exposeFunction('__addImageData', data => { });
    await page.goto('file:///path/to/index.html');
    await page.evaluate(() => {        
        for(var i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            window.__draw();
        }
    })
    await browser.close();
  })();
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.__draw = function() {
            var data = new Uint8Array(1280*720*4);
            window.__addImageData(data);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the expected result?
Relatively fast running code
What happens instead?
Each call to window.__addImageData takes ~1 second. Calling the function without
the data is near instant.

Is there another way to pass large objects to exposed functions?

Comment: `console.log` is slow. Why is this in your code when you're considering performance? Also, `1280*720*4 = 3686400`. `3686400 * 600 = 2211840000`. That's a good deal of work you're asking to be done here so I'd not expect this to run very fast. Is this your actual workload? If so, you might want to multi-process it with a worker per core. Also, `exposeFunction` is only needed if your processing has to be done in Node. If you can do it in the browser, then you save serialization/deserialization and inter-process communication. In short: more details are necessary to properly assess the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I will give your suggestion serious consideration.